# Creating a legend using ggplot when marker type and color are variables not related to x and y & are passed outside aes()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set with latitude, longitude, and water level values. I am trying to show the location using geom_point() but the shape and color of the marker is based on the water level value. For example, if at a location, the water level is between 90 and 100, the marker is a blue colored square. If its between 25 and 75, the marker is a red circle. I amusing the code below.

```
map <- ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data=Location_data, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), 
       shape=Location_data$marker,colour=Location_data$colour,size=4 ,alpha=1)
```

Location_data is a data frame with latitude, longitude, and water level. Based on the water level, I assigned a marker type and marker color to the data frame. I want to create a legend which shows the marker used and the corresponding water level. So, "90-100" next to a blue square, "25-75" next to a red circle and so on.

This is my first time using ggplot and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Put your `shape=` and `colour=` inside the `aes()` and use `+scale_shape_identity()` and `+scale_colour_identity()`

Comment: @MrFlick. Thank you. How do I add breaks to shape and color identity? I know the labels but I am not sure how to add breaks.